# TypeError: descriptor 'isoformat' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I have a table with some columns which one of theme is 'date' type and is defined as below in sqlalchemy model class:

```
 ConfStartDate = db.Column(Date, nullable=False)
```

python gives me error **"TypeError: descriptor 'isoformat' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'"** when wants to read all and serializes the output using these codes:

```
papers = Paper.query.order_by(Paper.PaperID).all()
paper_schema = PaperSchema(many=True)
data = paper_schema.dump(papers)
return data
```

How can I pass this error?

Comment: I have figured out some records have '0000-00-00' value for ConfStartDate field and this value causes error. How can I tell schema to work with this value?

Comment: It isn't a real date.  IMO it is better to allow the field to be nullable instead of adding fictional dates as the default (I have had this issue ☠️, null was easier to deal with in practice than 0000-00-00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed default value from '0000-00-00-' to NULL As Lucas Scott mentioned in comments and the problem get solved.